# ScrollBar in WPF not displaying properly and getting over tabcontrol

Tags: c#, wpf

So, when I create a new scrollbar the tab gets it. But when I scroll, it gets over the application menu too. I can't seem to find the solution and I tried everything.

My guess is that it's inside the dockpanel as well, but I don't know how to set it since if I added a new dockpanel it will say that "The property Content is set more than once."

Below you can see the code:

```
<Window
    xmlns:ribbon="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Windows.Controls.Ribbon;assembly=RibbonControlsLibrary"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ContabilitateMainWPF.Forms.Main"
    xmlns:WPF="clr-namespace:ContabilitateMain.Controls.WPF" x:Class="ContabilitateMainWPF.Forms.Main.FrmMainRibbon"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="Main" Closing="Window_Closing" Loaded="Window_Loaded" WindowState="Maximized" Icon="/ContabilitateMain;component/Imagini/new_window-512.png" WindowStyle="ToolWindow">
<DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
    <ribbon:Ribbon DockPanel.Dock="Top " Margin="0,-22,0,0">

        <ribbon:Ribbon.ApplicationMenu>
            <ribbon:RibbonApplicationMenu SmallImageSource="D:\PlasticWork\ContabilitateNou\ContabilitateMainWPF\Imagini\menu.png">
                <ribbon:RibbonApplicationMenu.AuxiliaryPaneContent >
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" >
                        <GroupBox>
                            <Label Content="Ceva in group box" />
                        </GroupBox>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </ribbon:RibbonApplicationMenu.AuxiliaryPaneContent>
                <ribbon:RibbonApplicationMenuItem x:Name="Salveaza" Header="Salveaza" />
            </ribbon:RibbonApplicationMenu>
        </ribbon:Ribbon.ApplicationMenu>
        <ribbon:RibbonTab x:Name="OptiuneaA" Header="Coloana A" MouseUp="OptiuneaA_MouseUp">
            <ribbon:RibbonGroup x:Name="T1" Header="Optiunea 1">
                <ribbon:RibbonButton x:Name="NouTab" Label="Tab PNG" LargeImageSource="D:\PlasticWork\ContabilitateNou\ContabilitateMainWPF\Imagini\new_window-512.png" Click="NouTab_Click"/>
                <ribbon:RibbonButton x:Name="AltNouTab" Label="Tab JPG" LargeImageSource="D:\PlasticWork\ContabilitateNou\ContabilitateMainWPF\Imagini\new.jpg" Click="AltNouTab_Click"/>
            </ribbon:RibbonGroup>
            <ribbon:RibbonGroup x:Name="T2" Header="Optiunea 2">
                <ribbon:RibbonButton x:Name="NouTab2" Label="Tab Nou" LargeImageSource="D:\PlasticWork\ContabilitateNou\ContabilitateMainWPF\Imagini\new_window-512.png"/>
                <ribbon:RibbonButton x:Name="AltNouTab2" Label="Tab Secund" LargeImageSource="D:\PlasticWork\ContabilitateNou\ContabilitateMainWPF\Imagini\new.jpg"/>
            </ribbon:RibbonGroup>
        </ribbon:RibbonTab>
        <ribbon:RibbonTab x:Name="NouTab1" Header="Coloana B">
            <ribbon:RibbonGroup x:Name="T3" Header="Optiunea 1">
                <ribbon:RibbonButton x:Name="NouTab3" Label="Tab Nou" LargeImageSource="D:\PlasticWork\ContabilitateNou\ContabilitateMainWPF\Imagini\new_window-512.png"/>
                <ribbon:RibbonButton x:Name="AltNouTab3" Label="Tab Secund" LargeImageSource="D:\PlasticWork\ContabilitateNou\ContabilitateMainWPF\Imagini\new.jpg"/>
            </ribbon:RibbonGroup>
        </ribbon:RibbonTab>
    </ribbon:Ribbon>
    <TabControl x:Name="actionTabs" DockPanel.Dock="Right" Background="White" SelectionChanged="actionTabs_SelectionChanged" >
            <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Height="15" Width="100">
                    <TextBlock Width="80" Text="{Binding Header}"/>
                    <Image Source="D:\PlasticWork\ContabilitateNou\ContabilitateMainWPF\Imagini\close.png" Width="20" Height="20" MouseUp="Image_MouseUp"/>
                </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </TabControl.ItemTemplate>
        <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:Name="TabItem1">
                <ScrollViewer>
                <UserControl Content="{Binding Content}" Margin="0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
               </ScrollViewer>
            </DataTemplate>
            </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
        </TabControl>

</DockPanel>
```

I expected to show to scroll only the tab, but it scrolls all the screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So apparently, the bug was because I tried to add a scrollbar to a window form, which was called from `<UserControl Content="{Binding Content}"` which was inside the tabcontrol. For some reason they connected eachother. I fixed it by adding the `Scrollviewer` to the `UserControl`, which looked something like this:

```
 `<UserControl x:Class="ContabilitateMainWPF.Controls.TestUserControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ContabilitateMainWPF.Controls"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300" SizeChanged="UserControl_SizeChanged">
    <ScrollViewer>
        <Grid x:Name="Grid">
            <Button x:Name="button" Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Margin="199,0,0,0"/>
            <Button x:Name="button_Copy" Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="141,91,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75"/>
            <Button x:Name="button_Copy1" Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="30,195,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75"/>
            <Button x:Name="button_Copy2" Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="199,261,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75"/>
            <Label x:Name="label1" Content="LabelTest" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="62,127,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        </Grid>
    </ScrollViewer>
</UserControl>`
```

Hope this helps someone one day.